# How to add a button in UIScrollView with addSubview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, addsubview

I am new to iOS development and I have a problem with `UIScrollView`. First of all, I've created a Scroll View in a storyboard and added

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroll;
```

in view controller handler

In the `viewDidLoad` method I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100.0,100.0); // Have to set a size here related to your content.
    // You should set these.
    self.mainScroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    self.mainScroll.minimumZoomScale = .5;  // You will have to set some values for these
    self.mainScroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    self.mainScroll.zoomScale = 1;

    UIButton* b = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [b setBounds:CGRectMake(.0f,0.f,100.0,100.0)];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:b];
}
```

But the button does not appear in the simulator. However if I add a button on storyboard in the IB, the button appears and I can scroll the view.

How can I add the button in code?

Comment: Are you using ARC? You should be if you're not.

Comment: make sure on button frame.Why you set bound whatever but .0f and 0.f is x and y cord of button.Please check frame size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.mainScroll addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

`bounds` and `frame` are not the same thing.

Use this code instead...

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
[self.mainScroll addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set scroll view contents size, something like the following code.

```
[self.mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

Comment: For some reason, for me, adding UIImageView subviews wouldn't scroll until I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.mainScroll.frame.origin.x + 25 ,self.mainScroll.frame.origin.y +25, 50, 44);
[self.mainScroll addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way to make a button from code is:

```
    UIButton* yourButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Your Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// if you set the button's image the title won't be visible, because button's title is "under" the image. I recomend you to use this if you have a cut and dried image.
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// if you set the button's background image, button's title will be visible 
    [yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBackgroundImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

// you can add target to the button, for handle the event when you touch it.
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleToucUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

// then add the button
    [self.view addSubview:yourButton];


- (void) handleToucUpInside:(id)sender{

    // here you can do anything you want, to handle the action


}
```